# using nicedit textarea value not saving into database using php

Tags: javascript, php, nicedit

Hi in the below code formatting table I am displaying using the nicedit but textarea data was not saving into a database.

I want to save the textarea value into database but it's not saving.

Can any one help me form this issue.

**html**

```
<tr>

            <td  style="width:100px;">Final Diagnosis:</td>
            <td style="width:200px;">   
                <textarea name="final_diagnosis" id="final_diagnosis" rows="2" cols="10"></textarea> 
            </td>

        </tr>
```

**script**

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
 new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('final_diagnosis');
 });
</script>
```

**new.php**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO discharge_patientcopy( ipd_reg_no,final_diagnosis)values(?,?)";

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        $sth->bindParam(1,$ipd_reg_no);


        $sth->bindParam(2,$final_diagnosis);


        ($sth->execute()) ? $token="success" : $token = "fail";
```

Answer (score 0):

NicEdit does not update the value of textarea, so you need to explicitly ask NicEdit to save the styling before you submit the form containing the textarea. This can be done by adding this line:

```
nicEditors.findEditor('<you_textarea_id>').saveContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing before calling php code just populate the value in textarea.

```
$('final_diagnosis').val($('.nicEdit-main').html());
```

or

```
document.getElementById('final_diagnosis').value = document.getElementsByClassName('nicEdit-main').innerHTML;
```